# Cast from Object to T

Tags: java, sockets, exception, casting, stream

I'am working on a class to simplify the handling of sockets. I have an InputStream which contains the received message and I want to cast it to another class defined by the user when he declare my class. So that's the code

```
private T read() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream (reader);
    T message = (T) ois.readObject();
    return message;
}
```

But it throws an exception : ClassNotFoundException
I d'ont know why. When T is of type String it works well but when it's a custom class it doesn't.

So I'm asking here :p
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't type T without define it first in method or class declaration.

Comment: Don't confuse casting with converting.  In Java you can only cast a reference to a type the object already is.  It won't convert say a `String` to a `MyClass`.  It will only let you cast an `Object` to a `MyClass` if the object referenced is already a MyClass.  If you want to convert, you have to handle this conversion explicitly.

Comment: @scorpion : T is my class declaration. Peter Lawrey : The datas in my inputStream is already of type MyClass

Answer (score 1):

Please double check whether all the types defined in your serialized object are also defined in your type `T`.

And I think @fabian is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try just making message an `Object`?

```
ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream (my_input_stream);
Object message = (Object) ois.readObject();
```

Or try adding `<T>` in the method declaration:

```
private <T> T read() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    ObjectInput ois = new ObjectInputStream (reader);
    T message = (T) ois.readObject();
    return message;
}
```

Comment: If I read into the inputStream bytes per bytes and I write them in an Object, it should work, Shouldn't it ?

Comment: That's strange because it works for me on a custom class

Comment: I update my question. actually the code is in a function. should I add <T> after the 'private' ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be a issue with the cast, but with reading the `Object`s from the `ObjectInputStream`. Here's the description of the `ClassNotFoundException` for  [`ObjectInputStream.readObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject--):

> Class of a serialized object cannot be found.

Which means that you forgot to add some of the classes of data in your `InputStream` to your classpath.

Comment: I don't think it comes from here because if put some System.out in the code, this line is passed correctly, the error is thrown at the cast

Comment: @omaflak: Isn't the cast in the exact same line as the call to `readObject()`??? AFAIK a `ClassNotFoundException` cannot be thrown by a simple cast when all necessary classes are in the classpath. And the fact that it works with `String` supports my claim. The full stack trace + error message could shed some light on this. Please add it to your question.

Comment: Yeah you're right sorry, i didn't read correctly your answer. But finally i think i am not going to cast my object. I am pretty sure it is possible but i prefere ask before.. Can i read bytes from the input stream and writes them into a new object ?

Comment: @omaflak: If you can represent your object with primitive data and serializable "core java types" (`String`, `File`, `ArrayList` of serializable objects, ... maybe restricted by a java 8 compact profile that you want to use), you can still safely use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`. Of course representing object graphs can be difficult. I wouldn't recommend operating on a byte level, unless you really need to, since most Objects don't offer a method to create them from bytes/convert them to bytes easyly.

Comment: Finally I resolved the problem. It was because of the class of the Object I wanted to send. The class had to be exactly the same on the client side and server side. And it was, except the package name which will also need to be the same! So that's it! ;)